# How to train neural networks on big sample sets in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, bigdata

I am trying to train neural network on big training set.

`inputs` consists of aprox 4 million of columns and 128 rows, and `targets` consisting of 62 rows.

`hiddenLayerSize` is 128.

The script is follows:

```
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
net.trainFcn = 'trainbfg';
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean squared error
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};
net.trainParam.show = 1;
net.trainParam.showCommandLine = 1;
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets, 'showResources', 'yes', 'reduction', 10);
```

When `train` starts to execute, Matlab hangs, Windows hangs or slow, swapping runs disk huge and nothing else happens for dozens of minutes.

Computer is 12Gb Windows x64, Matlab is also 64 bit. Memory usage in process manager varies during operation.

What else can be done except reducing train set?

If reducing train set, then to which level? How to estimate it's size except trying?

Why doesn't function displays anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly hard to diagnose such problems from remote, to the point that I am not even sure that anything anyone can answer might actually help. Moreover you are asking several questions in one so I will take it step by step. Ultimately I will try to give you a better understanding of the memory consumption of your script.

## Memory consumption

### Dataset Size and Copies

Starting from the size of the dataset you are loading in memory, assuming that each entry contains a double floating-point precision number, your training data set requires `(4e6 * 128 * 8) Bytes` of memory which roughly resolves to `3.81 GB`. If I understand correctly, your array of outputs contains `(4e6 * 62)` entries which become `(4e6 * 62 * 8) Bytes`, roughly equivalent to `1,15 GB`. So even before running the network training you are consuming circa `5GB` of memory.

Now yes MATLAB uses lazy copy so any assignment:

```
training = zeros(4e6, 128);
copy1 = training;
copy2 = training;
```

will not require new memory. However, any slicing operation:

```matlab
training = zeros(4e6, 128);
part1 = training(1:1000, :);
part1 = training(1001:2000, :);
```

will indeed allocate more memory. Hence when selecting your training, validation and testing subsets:

```matlab
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
```

internally the `train()` function could potentially be re-allocating the same amount of memory twice. Your grand total would now be 10GB. If you now consider that you operating system is running, along with a bunch of other applications, it is easy to understand why everything suddenly slows down. I might be telling you something obvious here but: your dataset is **very** large.

### Profiling Helps

Now, whilst I am pretty sure about my `5 GB` consumption calculation, I am not sure if this is a valid assumption. Bottom-line is I don't know the inside workings of the `train()` function that well.
This is why I urge you to test it out with [MATLAB's very own profiler](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/profile.html). This will indeed give you a much better understanding of function calls and memory consumption.

## Reducing Memory Usage

What can be done to reduce memory consumption? Now this is probably the question that has been haunting programmers since the dawn of times. :) Once again, it is hard to provide a unique answer as the solution is often dependent on the task, problem and tools at hand. Matlab has a, let's give it the benefit of the doubt, [informative page](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html#brh72ex-26) on how to reduce memory usage. Very often though the problem lies in the size of the data to be loaded in memory.

I, on one hand, would of course start by reducing the size of your dataset. Do you really need `4e6 * 128` datapoints? If you do then you might consider investing into dedicated solutions such as high-performance servers to perform your computation. If not you, but only you, must look at your dataset and start analysing which features might be unnecessary, to cut down the columns, and, most importantly, which samples might be unnecessary, to cut down the rows.

## Being optimistic

On a side note, you did not complain about any `OutOfMemory` errors from MATLAB, which could be a good sign. Maybe your machine is simply hanging because the computation is THAT intensive. And this too is a reasonable assumption as you are creating a network with `128` hidden layers, `62` outputs and running several epochs of training, as you should be doing.

### Kill The JVM

What you can do to put less load on the machine is to run MATLAB without the Java Environment (JVM). This ensures that MATLAB itself will require less memory to run. The JVM can be disabled by running:

```
matlab -nojvm
```

This works if you do not need to display any graphics, as MATLAB will run in a console-like environment.